# TabBar in iOS app with navigation event not working

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, tabbar

I trying to make simple navigation, if I press add button in tab bar I want to open a AddView (for testing purposes I using Settings View, because Add view is not ready yet. The main view now looks like this:

[image]

The code inside that view:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var UITabBar: UITabBarItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func settingsButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSettingsView", sender: self)
    }

    @IBAction func tabBarClicked(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item:UITabBarItem) {
        if(item.tag == 1) {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSettingsView", sender: self)
        }
    }

}
```

After I clicking add - nothing happens.

Edit: Somebody know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

`override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` must be missing.
Try adding the above method and also check segue connection in storyboards.

Comment: Can you provide me more details? I trying different tutorials but can't make it working properly. Im learning swift and I am beginner in it.